# Prove that a convergent sequence has only one limit point (Proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis

The title is self-explanatory. I'll be considering real sequences here and in particular, the sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $p$.

Consider a limit point $l$ of the seq s.t $l\neq p$. A limit point here is defined such that any $\epsilon$-ball centered at $l$ has infinitely many points.

(Unrelated but it is easy to show that $P$ is a limit point. We know that $\exists N$ s.t $\forall ~ n >N, ~ d(p_n,p) < \epsilon$ and this establishes the fact that there are infinitely many points in the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $p$).

***How do we show that $l\neq p$ can not be a limit point of the seq?*** I feel that the following theorem/lemma might be useful :

> $p_n$ converges to $p$ iff every open neighbourhood of $p$ has all but finitely many $a_n$.

Comment: I have added a possible solution as comments below the post by (Prof.) Kavi Rama Murthy. Please have a look into that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=\frac 1 2 d(l,p)$. Since $p_n \to p$ there exists $n_0$ such that $d(p_n,p) < r$ for  all $n \geq n_0$. Consider the open ball $B(l,r)$. This can contain $p_n$ only when $n <n_0$ (because $n >n_0$ implies $2r= d(l,p) \leq d(p_n,l)+d(p_n,p)<d(p_n,l)+r$ so $d(p_n,l) >r$). Hence $l$ is not a limit point.

Comment: If we consider $p,q$ to be the points of convergence, we will yield $p=q$ (from what has been done above) and arrive at the conclusion that the point of convergence is unique. My question was a bit different and this doesn't seem to answer it.

Comment: @charlesh I have edited my answer.

Comment: Can't this work : If the sequence converges at $l$ then there exists an infinite subsequence in $(l-\epsilon,l)$ or $(l,l+\epsilon)$ for some given $\epsilon$. Now consider the neighbourhood of $p$ (with radius $\epsilon'$) that doesn't coincide with $(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)$. For that we can choose the $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$ in a proper manner. This is possible since $l\neq p$. There should be some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $n>N \implies d(p_n,p) < \epsilon'$. Since $p$ is the converging point, any open neighbourhood should contain all but finitely many $p_n$.

Comment: But we have already created an infinite set of such elements which absolutely do not belong to the neighbourhood of $p$ with radius $\epsilon'$.

Comment: This might also work : Since the sequence is convergent, any infinite subsequence of the seq will be converging to $p$. _Proof :_ Consider the subseq $\{a_1, a_2,\cdots\}$ s.t $a_i = p_j$ for some $i,j$. Note that since $p_n \to p$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N$ s.t $n>N \implies d(p_n,p)<\epsilon \implies \exists M \text{ s.t } d(a_m,p) < \epsilon ~ \forall m>M$. Thus the subseq converges to $p$. Now since any infinite subseq is convergent at $p$, we see that the subseq we generated in the previous solution should also be convergent at $p$ thus showing $l = p$ (for $l$ to exist)